# How can I disable nginx gzip from PHP?

Tags: php, nginx, gzip

I am tyring to stop nginx from gzipping a single PHP request. I already have the following:

```
    @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
    @ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
    header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
```

According to everything I have found, that `X-Accel-Buffering` alone should disable gzip, however when I load this page from a browser, I can still see the header:

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
```

I'm using php7-fpm, nginx 1.10.1, debian8

EDIT:

I did a test using sleep() to delay the output. It looks like `header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');` IS working, however it only prevents buffering and not gzipping. I guess gzipping is working as a stream somehow.

I can see that if I output 1,000 bytes, looping over an echo statement with 1 char each, the browser receives about 11kb. If i echo a str_rep x 1000, then much less data is sent. There must be some overhead there.

Regardless, I need to disable gzip so that I can send a large amount of content and measure the download time. If it's gzipped, I don't know what the actual throughput is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nginx will not run gzip filter if `Content-Encoding` header is found in the upstream response. So, you can set `Content-Encoding: identity` header on the backend, and nginx will pass the response (and header) to the client without gzip process. `identity` means "not encoded".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any way to disable it explicitly, however I did find that there is a list of default mime-types that will be encoded by the gzip module.

Since the data doesn't have to be read and is just being sent as a speed test, changing the content type to anything other than that list will prevent it from being gzipped.

```
header('Content-Type: raw/data');
```